# Need some help with multiple integration regarding a Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, multiple-integral, integral-transforms

I am looking at a multiple integral given in equation 3.1 of [this paper,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.08951.pdf) which is a Fourier transform, with $b = |\vec{b}|$ and $p = |\vec{p}|$:

$$ \hat{f}(b) \equiv \int d^{D-2} \vec{p} \, e^{i\vec{b}.\vec{p}} \, \frac{f(p)}{p^{D-3} \, \text{vol} S^{D-3}} = \Gamma \left( \frac{D-2}{2}\right) \int_0^{\infty} dp f(p) \frac{J_{\frac{D-4}{2}}(pb)}{(pb/2)^{\frac{D-4}{2}}}.$$
Here $J$ denotes the standard Bessel function. The factor $p^{D-3} \, \text{vol} S^{D-3}$ in the denominator is for convenience, it partially cancels with the measure. I substituted $e^{i\vec{b}.\vec{p}} = e^{i{b}{p} \cos \theta}$, but it did not give me a correct answer.

Additionally, in equation 3.2, they claim that the following equation follows from the above Fourier transform:
$$ \int_0^{\infty} dp \, f(p) \, \frac{8\pi G}{p^2} = \int_0^{\infty} db \, \hat{f}(b)\, \frac{8\pi G b}{D-4}.$$
How do I see these two statements? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I not really know the topics the paper talks about, but to me it seems the author used a common trick used in Fourier transforms when you have angular symetries: they made a change of variables to polar coordinates (which require the inclussion of a Jacobian and not just replacing $e^{i\vec{b}.\vec{p}} = e^{i{b}{p} \cos \theta}$ - in the standard transform is adding a radial term, but because of the volume included maybe other things could arise), and in the complex exponential kernel appears a term dependent in the angle, and if the integrand is independent of the angular coordinate (haves angular symetry), this complex exponential angular term becomes a Bessel function dependent only of the radial coordinate (actually, the Fourier Transform becomes a Hankel Transform, which resultant function depends only in the radial coordinate).

The derivation is not so short, but it isn't so hard anyway, I let you a link with the full explanation [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241069465_Two-Dimensional_Fourier_Transforms_in_Polar_Coordinates).... I hope it was you were asking for.

Comment: I am taking into account the radial term from the Jacobian which is why I mentioned the partial cancellation.

Comment: If you already know the methods shown in the link, there is nothing more I could help. But maybe I can give you an advice: in my short time using MSE, I have noted that if you state a mistake in the question you get lots of answers, but if you ask what is happening are much more less the comments you receive... so, I encourage you to add at the end of you question an "added later" part showing step by step your calculations seeking to someone to find the mistake (even if they are none, author sometimes made mistakes too), and you add the tag "solution-verification". Good luck.